# Parliament graph with r-highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

Can someone tell me why this graphic is not drawn in R? I have some graphics in which this happens and I found no solution. It shows like lollipop graph...

thanks in advance..

```
library(highcharter)

    name <- c('A','B')
    y <- c(40,60)
    color <- c('#4185F3','#427CDD')
    label <- c('A1','B1')

    parliament <- data.frame(name, y, color, label)

highchart() %>%
    hc_chart(type='item') %>%
    hc_title(text='Highcharts item chart') %>%
    hc_subtitle(text='Parliament visualization') %>%
    hc_plotOptions(series=list(dataLabels=list(enabled = TRUE,  format='{point.label}'),center=c('50%', '88%'),startAngle=-100,endAngle=100)) %>%
    hc_legend(labelFormat='{name} <span style="opacity: 0.4">{y}</span>') %>%
    hc_add_series(data=parliament,name='Representatives',keys=c('name', 'y', 'color', 'label')) %>%
    hc_tooltip(enabled=FALSE) %>%
    hc_credits(enabled = TRUE, text = "Plataforma SegmentaNet",href = "https://segmentanet.com", target="_blank") %>%
    hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? It looks like your graph shows exactly what you give it. One datapoint at  y = 40 and another at y = 60.

Comment: I expect a chart like this (only with two parties, 60-40) https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parliament-chart

Comment: Did you get a solution yourself? I'm stuck with that same problem.

Answer (score 1):

nowadays, it runs properly ...

```
    name = c('Mixto','EH-Bildu','EAJ-PNV', 'C\'s', 'Plural', 'ERC', 'UP', 'VOX' , 'PP', 'PSOE')
  y= c(9, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 35, 52, 87, 120)
  label=c('Mixto','EH-Bildu','EAJ-PNV', 'C\'s', 'Plural', 'ERC', 'UP', 'VOX' , 'PP', 'PSOE')
  color=c("silver","#a3c93f","#1f813d","#ed5d19", "lightgreen", "#fce549", "#673165", "#66bc29", "#00a0e1", "#e30613")
  
  data <- data.frame(name, y, label, color)
  
  highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(type = "item") %>%
      hc_title(text = 'Highcharts item chart') %>%
      hc_subtitle(text = 'Parliament visualization') %>%
      hc_legend(enable = TRUE, labelFormat = '{name} <span style="opacity: 0.4">{y}</span>') %>%
      hc_add_series(
          name = 'Spanish Parliament',
          data = data,
          keys = c('name', 'y', 'label', 'color'),
          dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.label}'),
          startAngle = -100,
          endAngle = 100,
          #center = c('50%', '88%'),
          size = '80%')
```

sessionInfo()

```
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] highcharter_0.8.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        pillar_1.5.1      compiler_4.0.4    xts_0.12.1       
 [5] tools_4.0.4       digest_0.6.27     jsonlite_1.7.2    lubridate_1.7.10 
 [9] evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_1.0.0   tibble_3.1.0      lattice_0.20-41  
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10      igraph_1.2.6      DBI_1.1.1        
[17] curl_4.3          yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.22         stringr_1.4.0    
[21] dplyr_1.0.5       knitr_1.31        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6      
[25] htmlwidgets_1.5.3 grid_4.0.4        tidyselect_1.1.0  data.table_1.14.0
[29] glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.2       rmarkdown_2.7    
[33] TTR_0.24.2        purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.1.3       magrittr_2.0.1   
[37] backports_1.2.1   ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1 rlist_0.4.6.1    
[41] rsconnect_0.8.16  assertthat_0.2.1  quantmod_0.4.18   utf8_1.2.1       
[45] stringi_1.5.3     broom_0.7.5       crayon_1.4.1      zoo_1.8-9
```

regards