# HighcharteR facetted item type chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to make a `highcharter` item type plot, but I can't make the groups nor the facets like I need. I've been following the existing examples given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327881/parliament-graph-with-r-highcharter) and in the [highcart's API](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/item-chart) documentation, but I haven't been able to adapt them to what I need.

The [plot data is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bt0sJ7TJyXnSP-4N5rFUCYj7ykMxTo1i/view?usp=sharing). Using said data; this is what I got using `ggplot2` + `plotly` in the meantime. Can you help me replicate this using `highcharter`?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplotly(ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, y, size = 3, color = Partido, text = name, label = Partido)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~`¿Cómo votó?`)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more when you say: "but I haven't been able to adapt them to what I need."? Do you want to replicate those plots or did you replicate them well but need to add additional features to it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `list()` already converts to an items object, like example from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540244/how-to-build-an-organization-chart-with-highcharter).

```
data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal'),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain'),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England'))
```

Probably module `modules/item-series.js` not exist on Highcharter, you can report request for adding on https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues.